# passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast C

Tags: c, strcmp

I'm trying to compare a 2D array with a char but it keeps sending me this error and pointing at the array.

```
if ((strcmp(matrixarray[j+k][i], "X"))==0 || (strcmp(matrixarray[j+k][i], currentword))==0)
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
char wordsarray[8][7] = {"kalnas", "namas", "vanduo", "dama", "rasa", "ola", "mia", "jis"};
char matrixarray[6][7] = {"XOXXOX", "OOOOOO", "XOXXOX", "XOOOOX", "XOXOXX", "XOOOXX"};
char currentword = wordsarray[0][0];
int maxlen = 7 - sizeof(currentword);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j <= maxlen; j++){
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
                    if ((strcmp(matrixarray[j+k][i], "X"))==0 || (strcmp(matrixarray[j+k][i], currentword))==0)
                        matrixarray[j+k][i] = currentword;
                    else
                        matrixarray[0][0] = 'X';
                }
```

Comment: Type of `matrixarray`??

Comment: everything is char

Comment: You're trying to compare a `char` to `char *`, which of course makes no sense.  If you *only* want to compare the single character, then use `matrixarray[j+k][i] == 'X'`.  If you want to compare more than one character, then you need to have a null-terminated string for the first argument.

Comment: This compiler message is actually quite self-explanatory. Still we get like a dozen of these FAQ questions every week. Look, even if you don't understand a thing about the compiler message, I could as well tell you "BAD STUFF: argument 1 of strcmp" and then you should perhaps look at argument 1 of strcmp. Does it look correct? Hmm, no it doesn't. Dammit, the compiler was right again and the exact location where it told me to find the bug was where I could find the bug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the definition `char matrixarray[6][7]`, calling `strcmp(matrixarray[j+k][i], "X")` passes a character to `strcmp()`, but it needs a pointer.

Using `strcmp(&matrixarray[j+k][i], "X")` is the simplest change.  It will fix the compilation problem; it may or may not be correct algorithmically.

Indeed, it probably isn't correct.  The comparison cannot succeed unless it is looking at the last character before the null byte in `matrixarray[j+k]`.  It seems more likely that you should be comparing characters, not strings, so:

```
matrixarray[j+k][i] == 'X'
```

it probably more nearly correct.